# python 3 typeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I wrote the code below to find the inheritance of *args. but I got an error. I don't really understand the error, because I had the input and they were not none.

```
def third(*args, option=True):
    if len(args) == 2:
        word1, word2 = args
    else:
        word1 = args[0]

    if option:
        return word1, word2
    else:
        return word1


def hello(data, *args, option=True):
    print("the data is:", data)
    A, B = third(*args, option=True)
    print("the args are:", A, B)

def world(small, *args, option=True):
    return hello(small, *args)


if __name__ == "main":
    world("data","prediction")
```

Output:

```
the data is: data
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 2, in world
File "<stdin>", line 3, in hello
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: It should be `if __name__ == "__main__":`. When I fix that, I get other errors (unbound variable, as to be expected), but not the error you describe.

Comment: hi, i try to run the whole file in vscode and got nothing. I just noticed that i wrote "if __name__ == "__main__:" wrong so i got nothing from vscode. My result war from terminal. sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you are passing options=True which means the "third" function should always return  word1 and word2.
but len of args is one so word2 doesnot exist according to your if len(args) == 2 conditional.

so the "third" function returns only word1.
in your "hello" function you are trying to map that single element to two variables "A" and "B" by A, B = third(arguments) method which iterates the return values of the function but it is unable to do so because third is returning either one element or an error value(because you are trying to return word2 which doesnot exist).
that's why this error is occuring

Comment: i dont think that will resolve it because if option: return word1, word2 else: return word1 will still try to return both word1 and word2 because option is True( and word2 does not exist). add option = False before word1 = args[0] and that should resolve your problem

Comment: hi, thanks. that's the problem. i tried to reform the error of another one but did not make it.

Answer (score 0):

try this, should work:

```
def third(*args):
    if len(args) == 2:
        word1, word2 = args
        option = True
    else:
        option = False
        word1 = args[0]

    if option:
        return word1, word2
    else:
        return word1, None


def hello(data, *args):
    print("the data is:", data)
    A, B = third(*args)
    print("the args are:", A, B)

def world(small, *args):
    return hello(small, *args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    world("data","prediction")
```

Comment: hi, let's forget what i want the code to do and focus on the code you changed. I get the error that" ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: sorry for late reply I was on leave. I have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks. But that's not so beautiful if i get one extra arg and print the second as none. Maybe that's problem i want to understand. btw, happy new year:)